# Получение ссылок VK видео для открытия во внешнем плеере Android (parse)

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Например, https://vk.com/video206493873_456239050
или
https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=206493873&id=456239050&hash=a4990fb005d0912f&hd=2

Как можно получить из вышеупомянутых ссылок на VK-видео временные прямые ссылки 360p,480p,720p видео в приложение Android, чтобы можно было их использовать для открытия во внешнем плеере (какое-либо видео приложение Android, например, MX Player).

p.s. нужно получать ссылки и, чтобы при этом пользователям приложения не требовалось входить под своей учетной записью VK (то есть такого в приложение и не предполагается, что можно еще логиниться)

Comment: Через API? Все остальные методы ненадёжны.

Comment: @VladD ну и каким образом? Где мне токены брать? Было бы всё так просто.

Answer (score 3):

1. Через официальный api можно получить ссылку на страницу с плеером, откуда url можно вытащить банальной регуляркой.
2. Парсить al_video.
3. Можно через сервисы типа Savefrom и т.д.
4. С помощью регулярок парсим код на наличие строки с параметром vtag и вытаскиваем идентификатор
5. Строим прямую ссылку:
   `465.gt3.vkadre.ru/assets/videos/идентификатор-id видеозаписи.vk.формат`